# Why does the GUID show in my Column information when using spgridview?

Tags: 2010, web-part, spgridview

I am using spgridview to collect document information from multiple document libraries in my SharePoint 2010 publishing site.

When the column information is displayed, it seems that a GUID or something is displayed alongside the textual column name.  for example:

```
Anaesthisiology|6bff78d4-ef67-440a-b0f5-1bd32e28c754
```

The following is my sourcecode for this logic:

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        getData();
    }

     public void getData()
     {
         DataTable dt = new DataTable();
         DataRow dr;
         DataColumn dc;

         SPSite curSite = SPContext.Current.Site;
         SPWebCollection subSites = curSite.AllWebs;

         dc = new DataColumn("Title", Type.GetType("System.String"));
         dt.Columns.Add(dc);
         dc = new DataColumn("SubSection", Type.GetType("System.String"));
         dt.Columns.Add(dc);
         dc = new DataColumn("SubSubSection", Type.GetType("System.String"));
         dt.Columns.Add(dc);
         dc = new DataColumn("Created", Type.GetType("System.DateTime"));
         dt.Columns.Add(dc);
         dc = new DataColumn("SiteUrl", Type.GetType("System.String"));
         dt.Columns.Add(dc);

         for (int i = 0; i < subSites.Count; i++)
         {
             SPListCollection lists = subSites[i].Lists;

             foreach (SPList list in lists)
             {
                 if (list.Title == "Clinical")
                 {
                     SPQuery myquery = new SPQuery();

                     myquery.Query = "<GroupBy><FieldRef Name='SubSection' /></GroupBy><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='SubSection' /></OrderBy>";

                     SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(myquery);

                     foreach (SPListItem item in items)
                     {
                         if (item != null)
                         {
                             dr = dt.NewRow();

                             dr["Title"] = item["Title"];                                 
                             dr["SubSection"] = item["SubSection"];
                             dr["SubSubSection"] = item["SubSubSection"];
                             dr["SiteUrl"] = subSites[i].Url + 
                             "/DSTs/Forms/DispForm.aspx?ID=" 
                             + item["ID"].ToString(); ;

                             dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                         }
                     }
                 }
             }
         }

         dt.DefaultView.Sort = "SubSection";

         HyperLinkField colTitle = new HyperLinkField();
         colTitle.HeaderText = "Title";
         colTitle.DataTextField = "Title";
         string[] SiteUrl = { "SiteUrl" };
         colTitle.DataNavigateUrlFields = SiteUrl;
         colTitle.NavigateUrl = "SiteUrl";
         spLibraryView.Columns.Add(colTitle);

         BoundField colSubSection = new BoundField();
         colSubSection.DataField = "SubSection";
         colSubSection.HeaderText = "SubSection";
         spLibraryView.Columns.Add(colSubSection);

         BoundField colSubSubSection= new BoundField();
         colSubSubSection.DataField = "SubSubSection";
         colSubSubSection.HeaderText = "SubSubSection";
         spLibraryView.Columns.Add(colSubSubSection);

         spLibraryView.AllowGrouping = true;
         spLibraryView.AllowGroupCollapse = true;
         spLibraryView.GroupField = "SubSection";

         spLibraryView.DataSource = dt;
         spLibraryView.DataBind();
     }
```

I added a watch to the value item["SubSection"] and it shows the following:

```
{Anaesthisiology|6bff78d4-ef67-440a-b0f5-1bd32e28c754}
```

drilling down, the Label property shows:

```
"Anaesthisiology"
```

Why does the GUID show, and if I am using the wrong property how might I access the "Label" property via code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use a Regex.Replace call to parse?

```
string strSubSection = item["SubSection"];
Regex.Replace(strSubSection, "((.*))|.*", "$1");
dr["SubSection"] = strSubSection;
```

Comment: Yes, i could definately do that - thank you.  It does seem somewhat of a 'bandaid fix' though.  I am still curious as to why this is showing up in the first place, and how to just pull the column name without the GUID.  If I cannot, I will use your method - thx!

Comment: You'll have to add a using statement to the top of the file:
    using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

Comment: I use this all the time to parse data returned from SP lists.

Comment: ok this is normal when working with lists?  I was unaware - this is the first actual coding piece I have worked on that uses SPlists.  Thanks!

Comment: You can use regular expressions in many languages. They're very powerful. Take a look here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: this syntax doesn't strip out everything past the "|" : "((.*))|.*", "$1"  Would you be able to provide a regex expression that will strip out everything past the pipe ("|")?

Comment: hmm, I didn't test it but I thought that would work. You might need to escape the pipe, but I didn't think you did. What is it returning?

Comment: yeah, you have to escape it"((.*))\|.*"

Comment: ((match)) stores match in register 1, then the whole string is replaced by the contents of register 1 "$1", so you match the whole string, and then replace it with what was left of the pipe.

Comment: Did it work? If so, wanna mark this as the answer for me?

Answer (score 0):

THis is because the field value is a `TaxonomyFieldValue`. It's tostring method will return the contents of the field, which is stored in the format `TERMLABEL|TERMID`.

You'd have to add a `OnRowDatabound` event to your grid, get the currently bound dataitem, get the correct field, the cast to TaxonomyFieldValue, and display the TermLabel only